# cannot seem to get boost and quantlib directories to align

Tags: c++, eclipse, visual-studio-2010, quantlib

I have tried a number of different methods to try and get QuantLib to work on my windows machine. I would prefer to have QuantLib running in eclipse (so if anybody has any help in this direction I would be much appreciated!).

However, most online tutorials give their instructions using Visual Studio so I decided to try and get it working using this. I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7LR7JK-ebcs&t=340s) tutorial *to a T* and I still cannot get it working.

I have a folder looking like the following:

(My computer >> Documents >> cplusplus)

[image]

Next I enter the "QuantLib" folder and open the file "QuantLib.sln" where I enter visual studio.

I highlight the two projects in the solutions folder and select the wrench / properties tab

[image]

Which brings me to this tab:

[image]

Note that `Todas las config = all config` and `Todas las plataformas = all platforms` from minute 5.55 of the Youtube video.

I then go to "Directorios de VC++" - "VC Directories" and apply the following settings:

[image]

I then click "build /Compilar" -> build solution

I get the following error:

[image]

So how can I match `Boost`up with `Quantlib` and `C++` - I like `eclipe` but at this stage I just want to understand the `quantlib` package

EDIT:

In the video the screen shot is the following:

[image]

Where I have in the `intermediate directory` the following: `.\build\$(qlCompilerTag)/\$(Platform)\$(Configuration)\` which is different to the video. Additionally they have the following which includes an `(includePath)` addition to the `include directoies`  tab:

[image]

Just some additional observations I noticed...

EDIT 2:  I have also modified the `directorios intermedio` line to match the Youtube videos results. It was set at some default value beforehand. (i.e. `qlCompilerTag)/` was something differnet.

EDIT 3:

I changed the directories:

[image]

and get this ouput:

[image]

EDIT 4:

(removed the underscore)

[image]

With the following output:

##### EDIT (Following the official documentation)

I think I managed to solve the main issue I was having but now I am getting a new issue.

When I build the solution I get the following error:

[image]

When I go to the folder `C:\Users\Matt\Documents\cplusplus\boost_1_73_0\lib64-msvc-14.1` I locate the following files.

[image]

So Visual Studio is looking for the wrong files. What have I done wrong here? I downloaded the 64 bit version of boost? Is there a 32 bit version?

Comment: Change `C:\Users\Matt\Documents\cplusplus\boost_1_73_1_0\boost` to `C:\Users\Matt\Documents\cplusplus\boost_1_73_1_0` (I think).

Comment: I added an EDIT with your suggestion.

Comment: You have an unwanted trailing underscore there (`_`)

Comment: I have also removed that and I still get the error...

Comment: Did you try the official instructions from the QuantLib site? (https://www.quantlib.org/install/vc10.shtml) If they don't work, I'd very much like to know what's wrong and how to improve them.

Comment: I am following the instructions and now I obtain a new error. I put the screen shots of the error under the last `EDIT` titled `##### EDIT `.

Comment: I "think" I have got it working. I run the `TestingQuantLib` and I get the same output. I had a few versions of Visual Studio installed (enterprise and 2 community versions) I removed all of them and only installed the community version. Seems to work.